# modifying shared global variables in python flask application

Tags: python, variables, flask, global

I have a Python flask web app that needs a global variable shared between multiple requests. The app is long-running, and the value of the global variable changes occasionally.

**Here is what the code looks like...**

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from my_module import my_function

data = 0 # global variable initialize to 0

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/do/some/work', methods=[GET])
def work():
    my_function(data)

@app.route('/modify/global/var', methods=[GET])
def modify():
    global data
    data = 5

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**This is the issue at hand...**

The first time the application loads, the value for `data = 0`.

I hit `/do/some/work` endpoint 5 times, and I get consistent results back where `my_function` uses `data = 0`.

Then I hit `/modify/global/var` endpoint once, and it modifies global var data to `data = 5`.

I, again, hit `/do/some/work` endpoint 5 times. Now it gives inconsistent results. Sometimes it uses `data = 5`, other times it uses `data = 0` from the first initialization.

The only solution that works is restarting the app with `data` initialized to the correct value... but, of course, that's not an option when the app goes live in production...

**This is what I've tried so far...**

1. Putting the global variable in a separate module `separate_module.py`, in a class. Example below...

separate_module.py

```
class GlobalData(object):
    def __init__(self): 
        self.data = 0
    def modify(self):
        self.data = 5
```

... and then `import`ing `GlobalData`, instantiating an object of it and using it to modify the global var `data` and passing it to `my_function()`.

```
from separate_module import GlobalData

...

gd = GlobalData()

...

def work():
    my_function(gd.data)

...

def modify():
    gd.modify()
```

Still producing the same inconsistent results...

2. Deleting and reinstantiating `GlobalData` object in `global` scope of `app.py` before modifying it.

`def modify():`

```
    del gd
    global gd
    gd = GlobalData()
    gd.modify()
```

... I assumed doing a hard delete on the object would remove all references of the old data from memory, but still producing the same results...

**Question...**

What am I doing wrong? And how can I fix it?

Comment: If you are serving this as a proper multithreaded/process application, each variable per instance will be independent from the rest.  Please use some external instance store (like sqlite) will ensure the data is properly synchronized because you won't run into collision issues.

Comment: That makes perfect sense! I completely overlooked the fact that it's running multithreaded... Thanks, @metatoaster for bringing it to my attention and offering the solution of using some external instance store.